# Retrieving values of json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am sending an AJAX request to server and retrieving a response as a json object from the server with javascript code to my android application. I know the key values of the json object(ID, name, status, etc.) but I do not know how to get their values.(100, Mark, success, etc.) I need those data for processing for some other task. Can someone please tell me how to extract data from that json object. When I use alert(http.responseText); as follows I get the json object displayed. I need to get the values out of it.

**method used to receive response**

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Handler function for call back on state change.
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
        alert(http.responseText);
```

**json object I receive**

```
{"header": {"ID":100,"name:"Mark"},"body":{"status":"success"}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you get *exactly* what you posted? That "JSON" is not JSON since it contains a syntax error (missing quote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert The string to an object by doing `var response=JSON.parse(http.responseText);`

Just treat it like any object - `console.log(response['name'])`

Comment: thanks a lot mate! :) I had put doble quotations and got error.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to a JavaScript object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
```

Since some legacy browsers do not have native JSON support you should include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js) to shim it for those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to eval the http.responseText to get the json object...

but using eval is not recommended, so you can use the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library to parse the text into json object..

or else you can even use the library like jquery and use function parseJSON to get it converted to json object